# Не удалось резрешить ресурс, как исправить?

Tags: wpf

[image: Д]Не пойму, почему оно не разрешает данный код:

А именно:
`SettingsHoverBrush, SettingsPressedBrush, SettingsDisabledBrush`

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SettingsHoverBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SettingsPressedBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SettingsDisabledBrush}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="contentPresenter" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: А сами ресурсы где?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Не понял вопроса... Какие ресурсы? Я открыл xaml скомпилировал его, и получил такую вот ошибку

Comment: Вы в XAML, если перевести на человеческий, говорите "Слыш, программа, я хочу чтоб когда объект был не активен, то у элемента с именем `border` менялся его задний фон на тот, что в ресурсах под именем `SettingsDisabledBrush`". Программа такая "Ок ок, да только где этот `SettingsDisabledBrush` то? Я его не найду!". Собственно вопрос в силе, вы ссылаетесь на цвет, который у вас где то должен быть прописан, вопрос - где?